# what is the best way to enter multiple child records in a web form

Tags: user-interface

for example, we have a web form to let the user enter personal info such as address and phone number, then the user need to enter the spouse and dependents information. I usually use a gridview for this, but some users complain it is difficult to use. so what is the most user-friendly or conventional way to handle it?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use AJAX to do this. Usually a Button and/or programming triggered by an event to add form items.

For example:

Username:
Password:

(+) PHONE

.. then every time you add "+ PHONE" I would add a new set of text boxes for more phone numbers.

Comment: what is the easiest way ot add the new set of textboxes? suppose I put them in a div, is there any kind of clone method? thank you.

Comment: Typically you will have an inner frame that you will post stuff to.

I usually do IFRAME.outertext = "[NEW HTML CODE]<br><iframe code>"

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to have a more user-friendly form where the user fills in information for a single individual, and then an "add" button that takes the contents of the form and inserts it into the gridview where it can be reviewed while simultaneously clearing the rest of the form to allow another individual's info to be added.